# why is this css transistion menu not working in Chrome - horizontal menu?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have spent a few hours wondering what is wrong and fiddling with answers i found online but could not fix it. I am able to display the horizontal menu, but color of li element wont change on hover.
Please Help . I have just started working on a new website project and am a noob.
Here a snippet:

```css
ul{
       line-style-type:none;  
       overflow:hidden;
       background-color:#333;
       margin:0;
       padding:0px 
       }
 
    li{
      float:right;
      }
    li a{
     display:inline-block;
     color:white;
     padding:10px 10px;
     text-decoration:none;
     text-align:center;
 
        display:block;
    }
    li a: hover{
     background-color:#223;
     display:block;
     position:relative;
     }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#l">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#j">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#k">Contact Me</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is absolutely _no_ transition property in this CSS, so I do not know what you are expecting would happen.

Comment: `li a: hover` is invalid pseudo select. There mustn't be a space after `:`

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted a `transition`, and I'm assuming this is only for `background-color`, then you need to define the `transition` on the `li a` selector.

However, your `:hover` isn't working b/c you have `a :hover`, but needs to be `a:hover`

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3ch3901/)

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
</ul>

ul {
  list-style:none;  /* changed this as well, was incorrect */
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  float: right;
}

li a {
  /* you can also use "all", rather than specifying a specific transition, 
     however, when it's not needed, it's best to specify the actual 
     CSS to hit. If you have more than 1 transtion, you can break it up by
     using a comma, such as this: 
     transition: background-color .2s ease-in, color .2s ease-in; 
     Also do not forget to use prefixes for browsers (older), such as 
     -webkit-transition
     -moz-transition
     -ms-transition
     -o-transition
  */
  transition: background-color .2s ease-in; 
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #223;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: It might be best _not_ to suggest using `all` as it is a blanket cover and it means the users machine will try to optimise for everything, and that could needlessly require more power. Best to be specific. You might also want to mention (as the OP said he's a noob) the need for `prefixes` - mostly just `-webkit-` these days, but still.

Comment: You're correct in your suggestions. I stopped using prefixes since it's assumed, but I'll change.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide us the Html code too. But from my point of view the problem might be here

```
li { float: right; }
```

should be

```
li { float: left; }
```

and then

```
li a: hover{
    background-color:#223;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
```

should be `li a:hover` without a blank space between `a` and `:hover`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Correct, I guess, but there's no transitioning here as the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your hover class with this:

```
li a:hover{
            background-color:#223;
            display:block;
            position:relative;
         }
```

I just remove the space between a and hover